# How to escape an equal sign in an URL?

Tags: java, character-encoding, urlencode

In my RestAssured test I have:

```
String customerId = "1234";

given().queryParam("customerId=" + customerId)
        .spec(customerApi).auth().oauth2(token)
.when().log().ifValidationFails()
       .get("/api/v1/customers/latest")
.then()
       .assertThat()
       .statusCode(201);
```

...where I need to pass a query param with an `=` char.

This comes out encoded as follows:

```
https://customer-api.com/api/v1/customers/latest?customerId%3D1234
```

What is the cleanest way of resolving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing both parameter name and value as the parameter name to *RestAssured* which then gets escaped.
Just pass the actual value of the parameter as the second argument of [`queryParam(String, Object...)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/4.4.0/io/restassured/specification/RequestSpecification.html#queryParam-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-). The library will take care of the escaping of parameter name or value if necessary.

```java
.queryParam("customerId", customerId)
```

This should result in the following:

```
https://customer-api.com/api/v1/customers/latest?customerId=1234
```